# Head on svn log doesn't always stop

Tags: search, svn, logging, pipe, head

Consider this:

```
svn log -r HEAD:1 --search $pattern | head -4
```

Sometimes this command finds the necessary amount of lines (e.g. 4) and stops. But sometimes it just keeps searching (i.e. hangs) even after having found the necessary amount of lines.

I don't know on what it depends (whether it keeps searching or stops). I would like to know the reason and I would like to know how to modify my command so it always stops right after having found the necessary amount of lines (I don't want the `svn log` to search the entire svn history as this might take forever).

Answer (score 1):

Plain `svn log` will always continue showing the revision history from HEAD revision to 0 relevant to your query unless you kill the process (assuming that you don't use the `--limit` switch or specified some subtree like `/branches/myfeature`). Adjust your script to kill the process once it shows the required number of log messages.

Comment: Isn't it like built-in in the shell pipe functionality? I mean after having read 4 lines of input won't just `head` close the pipe or something (which would force ending `svn log` as well)?

Comment: @NPS I guess that you have to explicitly end the process. I'm not sure whether `head` closes the pipe and whether it kills the original `svn log` process.

Comment: But from what I see `head` does somehow kill the piped process when it gets the necessary amount of input. Consider `yes | head`. Apparently, `head` just interacts in a weird way with `svn log`. Because it also **does** stop for me, just not always.